# Dealing with a callback that must populate a field in another class's instance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a class `SomeAction` which implements `ISomeAction` (given to me), it has an async method that calls a non async void method which belongs to a class instance that is provided by a third party sdk. To handle the `void` in my async method, I use `TaskCompletionSource` which I intend on setting once I get the response from the third party. The problem is, the response from the service is in the form of a callback which uses a class `ThirdPartyCallbackClass` that the third party has a defined interface for.

So how can I take the `string` passed back to the `ThirdPartyCallbackClass` and use it to update the `TaskCompletionSource` instance in `SomeAction`

Here is the code (forgive any typos):

```
public class SomeAction : ISomeAction
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<string> fbtcs;

    public async Task<string> someTask()
    {
        var accessToken = await SomeAsyncMethod();
        return accessToken;
    }

    private async Task<string> SomeAsyncMethod()
    {
        fbtcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        TaskClass tc = new TaskClass();
        tc.CallThirdParty();

        return await fbtcs.Task;
    }
}

public class TaskClass
{
    public void CallThirdParty()
    {
        ThirdParty tp = new ThirdParty();
        var somePayload = "payload";
        ThirdPartyCallbackClass callback = new ThirdPartyCallbackClass();
        tp.VoidMethodWithCallback(somePayload, callback);
    }
}

public class ThirdPartyCallbackClass : IThirdPartyDefinedCallback
{
    public void OnSuccess(string p)
    {
        //At this point I want to take p and use it to update SomeAction's fbtcs instance string. Is my design wrong or is there a strategy for dealing with this?
       //If this was in my `SomeAction` instance I would try to do something like...

       //fbtcs.TrySetResult(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of `ISomeAction` to your post?

Comment: Is `VoidMethodWithCallback` asynchronous? If so, what asynchronous paradigm is it using? It doesn't seem to be using `Task<TResult>` or `IAsyncResult`, are you sure it isn't synchronous?

Comment: @Dai it is synchronous (ie it doesnt have an async before its void definition) and the interface just contains Task<string> someTask();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ThirdParty::VoidMethodWithCallback` is a synchronous method then you don't need to use `TaskCompletionSource` at all, you can call synchronous methods directly in an `async` or `Task<TResult>`-returning method:

```
public class SomeAction : ISomeAction
{
    public Task<String> SomeTaskAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult( this.SomeMethod() );
    }

    private String SomeMethod()
    {
        String value = new TaskClass().CallThirdParty();
        return value;
    }
}

public class TaskClass
{
    private class CallbackContainer : IThirdPartyDefinedCallback
    {
        public String ReturnedValue;

        public void OnSuccess(String p)
        {
            this.ReturnedValue = p;
        }
    }

    public String CallThirdParty()
    {
        ThirdParty tp = new ThirdParty();
        var somePayload = "payload";

        CallbackContainer callbackContainer = new CallbackContainer();

        tp.VoidMethodWithCallback( somePayload, callbackContainer );

        return callbackContainer.ReturnedValue;
    }
}
```

In the event that `SomeTaskAsync` is called directly from a UI thread or some other thread that should not block, then use `Task.Run` to run the synchronous method on a Thread-pool thread:

```
public class SomeAction : ISomeAction
{
    public Task<String> SomeTaskAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run( (Func<String>)this.SomeMethod );
    }
}
```

Note the standard (i.e. Microsoft) naming convention in .NET is to always have `Async` at the end of the name of any method which ultimately executes asynchronously (it doesn't necessarily need to be flagged with the `async` modifier: it could pass-through a `Task<T>` from another call, for example).

Comment: So this definitely does the job in terms of resolving my instance dependencies but I am still struggling with `return Task.Run( (Func<String>)this.SomeMethod );` This method will eventually return the value but it is too late, the value is always null. I added an await but doesn't seem to register. I am reading more about this stuff so maybe I can resolve soon.

Comment: @40Alpha Use your debugger to verify that `OnSuccess` is actually called and what the value of `.ReturnedValue` is when `CallThirdParty` returns.

Comment: Ya it was getting called with the value but it was taking too long... If I put the thread to sleep for 5 seconds in `SomeMethod` it would succeed. I ended up using the structure you suggested (nested class) but kept with setting the `TaskCompletionSource` once the callback got the value... I think I gave some faulty information in my question about the async 3rd party void but regardless your answer helped me find a solution. Although I am still confused by the differences with async voids and sync voids... The 3rd party is definitely async (so I think) but it doesnt have the async decoration.